# The common notation fo equlibrium point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is a multidimensional system of differential equations:
$$
\left\{
  \begin{array}{c}
    \dot x_1 = F_1(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n),\\
    \dot x_2 = F_2(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n),\\
    \ldots,\\
    \dot x_n = F_n(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n).\\
  \end{array}
\right.
$$
How I should designate a equlibrium point $x$ such that $\dot x_1 = 0, \, \dot x_2 = 0, \, \ldots \, \dot x_n = 0$? The index notation look ugly when we referring to the coordinates: notation $x_0$ gives $x_{0,1}, \, x_{0,2}$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its notation you are asking about, often people add a bar, tilde or something of the sort to avoid the double index, e.g., $\bar{x},\tilde{x}$, etc. Alternatively, you can use a different letter, e.g., "the fixed point $p$".